# Pushing notifications from Ruby On Rails to Android and IOS users using Parse

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, parse-platform

I'm building an application using Ruby On Rails. the app is supposed to  push notifications to android and IOS user using Parse RESTfull api. i have tried to use [parse-ruby-client](https://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client) but the documentation is poor and a don't get how it really works. i mean how to send a notification a specific user.

Comment: this is too broad of a question. what have you tried? post some code on what doesnt work.

Comment: I having a problem on understanding how it works or how to configure it with my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to send a notification to a specific user you first need to have channels for each user setup or query a specific installation. With parse and the rest api the easiest way I have found to send a notification to an individual user is to setup each user as a channel. When the user initially sets up the app on their device, I take either their username or email and use that as their channel. Then when I want to send a notification to a specific user I send to that channel.

In ruby to send to a channel you would use the following substituting your channel in place of Giants

```
data = { :alert => "This is a notification from Parse" }
push = Parse::Push.new(data, "Giants")
push.type = "ios"
push.save
```

For advanced targeting, for example, if you want to query a class and find iOS users with injury reports set to true you can use the following:

```
data = { :alert => "This is a notification from Parse" }
push = Parse::Push.new(data)
push.type = "ios"
query = Parse::Query.new(Parse::Protocol::CLASS_INSTALLATION).eq('injuryReports', true)
push.where = query.where
push.save
```

The push.type refers to the system type- iOS (ios), android (android), windows user (winrt or winphone).

Comment: i am not quit sure if you got my problem. i have an application that supports ios and android users and they use ruby on rails for storing data and provide some APIs. i need to use Parse in order to push notifications to my application users(ios & android). how parse uniquely identifies which device it should send the notification for i.e form the server (ruby on rails) to my application users.

Comment: If you are looking to trigger push notifications to a specific device channels is the way to do it. How you setup channels is completely up to you. The installation class is basically your individual device installations. From parse push notifications guide - channels: An array of the channels to which a device is currently subscribed. Targeting a specific device is easiest done with channels because you are in control of what channel each device is subscribed to. If you have a user with more than 1 device and you want to send to all devices setting username as the channel allows this.

Comment: If you choose to send only to each individual device then you can choose how you would like to setup each devices channel. You will need to add code to your app to subscribe a device to whichever method you choose.